# Graph is not displayed in shiny [R]

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am using shiny package in R to take input from user and plot the X and Y variable against each other as line plot.There is no error displayed.Everything is displayed except for the graph.Please can someone help why the graph is not displayed .Here is the **ui.r file**

```
library(shiny) # load the shiny package
setwd("C:/indiahacks2")
dat<-read.csv("final.csv")

# Define UI for application
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Header or title Panel 
  titlePanel(h4('Impulse Response on VAR MODEL', align = "center")),

  # Sidebar panel
  sidebarPanel(



    selectInput("Impulse", label = "1. Select the Impulse Variable", 
                choices = names(dat)), 
    selectInput("Response", label = "1. Select the Response Variable", 
                choices = names(dat)),


    sliderInput("Lag", "2. Select the number of histogram BINs by using the slider below", min=0, max=25, value=10),

    radioButtons("colour", label = "3. Select the color of histogram",
                 choices = c("Green", "Red",
                             "Yellow"), selected = "Green")
  ),

  # Main Panel
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text1"),
    textOutput("text2"),
    textOutput("text3"),
    textOutput("text3"),
    plotOutput("myhist")

  )

)
)
```

**Server.r**

```
library(shiny) # Load shiny package

dat<-read.csv("final.csv")

shinyServer(


  function(input, output) {

    output$text1 <- renderText({ 
      colm = as.numeric(input$Impulse)
      paste("Impulse Variable is", names(dat[colm]))

    })

    output$text2 <- renderText({ 
      paste("Color of plot is", input$radio)
    })

    output$text3 <- renderText({ 
      paste("Number of Lags is", input$Lag)
    })
    output$text4 <- renderText({ 
      colm = as.numeric(input$Response)
      paste("Response Variable is", names(dat[colm]))

    })

    output$myhist <- renderPlot(

      {
        colm = as.numeric(input$Impulse)
        colm1 = as.numeric(input$Response)
        plot(dat[,colm],dat[,colm1])})    
})
```

Comment: you need to use the `plot` command, not lines. `lines` is to used to add to an existing plot device, not to create one. `plot(dat[,colm],dat[,colm1],type="b")`

Comment: I changed the line command to  plot(dat[,colm],dat[,colm1]) but still no change

Comment: do you want an histogram or a bar graph?

Comment: A LINE scatter plot between two variables user selects

Answer (score 4):

So there a couple of things wrong with your script, upon further inspection:

1) `colm` cannot be referenced by `output$text4`. This is because of scoping...

2) When you comment-out the `output$text4` code I now receive an undefined column error in the `plot` call. This is because forcing your column choices to numeric returns `NA`.

Below should do what you are looking for.

Here is the server.R code:

```
library(shiny) # Load shiny package
dat<-read.csv("final.csv")

shinyServer(

function(input, output) {

    output$text1 <- renderText({ 
        colm = as.numeric(input$Impulse)
        paste("Impulse Variable is", columns()[2])

    })
    output$text2 <- renderText({ 
        paste("Color of plot is", input$radio)
    })

    output$text3 <- renderText({ 
        paste("Number of Lags is", input$Lag)
    })
    output$text4 <- renderText({ 
        colm = as.numeric(input$Response)
        paste("Response Variable is", columns()[2])

    })

    columns<-reactive({
        colm = as.character(input$Impulse)
        colm1 = as.character(input$Response)
        return(c(colm, colm1) )
    })

    output$myhist <- renderPlot(

        {
            plot(dat[,columns()[1]],dat[,columns()[2]],type="b")})
})
```

*Ui.R

```
# Define UI for application
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Header or title Panel 
titlePanel(h4('Impulse Response on VAR MODEL', align = "center")),

# Sidebar panel
sidebarPanel(



    selectInput("Impulse", label = "1. Select the Impulse Variable", 
                choices = names(dat)), 
    selectInput("Response", label = "1. Select the Response Variable", 
                choices = names(dat)),


    sliderInput("Lag", "2. Select the number of histogram BINs by using the slider below", min=0, max=25, value=10),

    radioButtons("colour", label = "3. Select the color of histogram",
                 choices = c("Green", "Red",
                             "Yellow"), selected = "Green")
),

# Main Panel
mainPanel(
    textOutput("text1"),
    textOutput("text2"),
    textOutput("text3"),
    textOutput("text4"),
    plotOutput("myhist")

)

)
```